# how to use denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in this question?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In [Need a hint: show that a subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ with no limit points is at most countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202943/need-a-hint-show-that-a-subset-e-subset-mathbbr-with-no-limit-points-is-a), the OP constructs an interval $N_{r_x}(x)$ for each $x \in E$ such that $N_{r_x}(x) \cap E = \{x\}$. It is then hinted that the solution follows from the denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to construct a map from $E$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ sending $x$ onto a rational number $q_x$ with $q_x \in N_{r_x}(x)$ (which always exists, since we can always pick a rational number between $x -r_x$ and $x+r_x$. However, how can we argue that this map is injective? Or is this not what is intended by the hint?

Comment: While the mapping you describe is not quite injective, the mapping that picks a rational between $x -r_x/2$ and $x + r_x/2$ will be. Can you prove why?

Comment: @MeesdeVries: should I try to prove that those intervals become disjoint?

Comment: that would certainly do the trick. :-)

Comment: @MeesdeVries I'll try it :)

Comment: @Mees Can you please explain why picking a rational in $(x-r, x+r)$ can't be injective? It seems like it is.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri, it can be but it doesn't have to be. E.g. if $E = \mathbb Z$, and for each $n$ we have $r_n = 1$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Oh you're right. I missed the intersections.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I tried to reach a contradiction by assuming that there was an element $z$ in the intersection of two such intervals. However, of $z \notin E$, then I'm not able to reach such a contradiction...

Comment: @MeesdeVries found it, a drawing does wonders :)

Comment: @MeesdeVries You should have written an official answer. The accepted answer claims that the open intervals $(x-r_x,x+r_x)$ are pairwise disjoint. This is not true for an arbitrary choice of $r_x > 0$ with the property $(x-r_x,x+r_x) \cap E = \{x\}$, but you clarified what to do.

Comment: @KritikerderElche, you are free to write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is valid.

Your map is injective because your open balls are pairwise disjoint.

If $x\ne y$ then your $q_x$ and $q_y$ are in two disjoint open balls centered at $x$ and $y$ so $q_x \ne q_y$, that is the set is disjoint.

Comment: I have troubles showing that the open balls are actually disjoint. Could you elaborate a bit more on this? MeesdeVries already hinted that cutting the radius in half definitely does the trick, but I haven't been able to prove this...

Comment: Found it, a drawing does wonders!

Comment: In general the open intervals need not be disjoint. Take $E = \{ 0, 1 \}$ and $N_{r_0} = (-1,1),  N_{r_1} = (0,2)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost The open intervals do need to be disjoint but you may pick them disjoint to make sure that the function is one-to -one.

Comment: Does "pick them disjoint" mean that you can somehow construct the $N_{r_x}(x)$ pairwise disjoint? How would that work?

Comment: The open balls are not disjoint.  The intersection of any two of those balls and E is empty which suffices for the injection.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Perhaps I have a mental block, but I still do not see how that could help. You choose rational $q_x \in N_{r_x}(x), q_y \in N_{r_y}(y)$ and have to show that $q_x \ne q_y$ if $x \ne y$. You certainly know that $N_{r_x}(x) \cap N_{r_y}(y) \cap E = \emptyset$, but what does this mean for $q_x,q_y$? It may happen that $q= q_x = q_y \in N_{r_x}(x) \cap N_{r_y}(y)$, but $q\notin E$.

Comment: See my answer where I show injectivity without using disjoint sets.  I dare you to prove the open sets are disjoint.   Otherwise your proof fails

Answer (score 1):

We can take $N_{r_x}(x) = (a_x,b_x)$ with $a_x, b_x \in \mathbb{Q}$. The *set* $M = \{ (a_x, b_x) \mid x \in E \}$ is countable because there are only countably many intervals with rational endpoints. Write $M = \{ N_i \}$ with finitely many or countably infinitely many $N_i$. We have $N_i \cap E = \{ x_i \}$ with $x_i \in E$. Then $E = \bigcup_{x \in E} N_{r_x}(x) \cap E = \bigcup_i N_i \cap E = \bigcup_i \{ x_i \}$.

Added:

You can also use this to produce an injection $i : E \to \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. For any $x$ choose $N_{r_x}(x) = (a_x,b_x)$ with $a_x, b_x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Define $i(x) = \langle a_x,b_x \rangle \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ (we use $\langle a_x,b_x \rangle$ to distinguish the pair from the interval $(a_x, b_x)$). If $\langle a_x,b_x \rangle = \langle a_y,b_y \rangle$, then $\{ x \} = (a_x,b_x) \cap E = (a_y,b_y) \cap E =\{ y \}$.

By the way, the above proof is based on the assumption that $E$ has no limit points in $E$ itself. It remains open whether this is the correct interpretation of the question whose prerequisite could also be understood in the sense that $E$ has no limit points in $\mathbb{R}$. What we have proved is certainly the more general case.